# With Nokogiri how can one insert Node object content into XML::Builder structures?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

With Nokogiri how can one insert Node object content into XML::Builder structures?

```
#source nodes
mynodes = [...array of Nodes...]

#where I want to dump source nodes
target_for_nodes = somebuilder.doc.xpath('//mydoc/mynodecollection').first

#drop the nodes into place
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(target_for_nodes) do |xml|
  mynodes.each do |node|
     xml.text node.to_xml  #gives escaped text- how to drop real XML here from the Node?
  end
end
```

It gives escaped text but it is not clear to me how to drop real XML here from the Node objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm. It seems I just need to use

```
xml << node.to_xml
```

rather than

```
xml.text node.to_xml
```

Cheers!

Comment: It is entirely amazing what one can find when reading the documentation.